# Inferred Property when integrating facebook

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am attempting to integrate Facebook open graph into my site but I ran it through the URL Linter (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint) and I get the error:

Inferred Property   The og:url property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The og:title property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

[Example](http://www.rizon.be/nl/work/107/ing3dtypo)

I'm concerned it's because my html is not valid or is missing something:

Comment: have you included an `og:url` meta tag?

Comment: Yes, including everything including fb:admins, fb:app_id, tested if everything. FB don't seems to like it, strange that if I test with information of www.rizon.be self it works, but we want to add project information with project picture, no general information. <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.rizon.be/site/nl/work/107/ing3dtypo" />

Comment: {edit} sorry, i see now that stackoverflow removed some of the formatting - that looks correct {edit again} - does that site actually work? there doesn't seem to be a DNS A record for 'rizon.be'

Comment: Site only works under the www. record (www.rizon.be), I will ask my client to make a A record for the * record. But in the metatags we always add the www. prefix

Comment: Oh, i see, stackoverflow removed the www, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently and found that the FB debugger at some point started producing this error when the problem is one of the other fields.

I checked the source on your website, and noticed you have used `fb:type` instead of `og:type`.

I suspect if you change

```
<meta property="fb:type" content="website"/>
```

to

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
```

...the problem will hopefully be resolved.

Comment: Tested, but no result. Maybe it's because the site in located in a dir /site (still in beta) , also we tested with the old rel="image_src" ,no luck either.

Strange: on www.rizon.be we use the image_src and this works well.

Comment: Changed the site to the root dir: http://www.rizon.be/nl/work/107/ing3dtypo  , no luck either.

Strange : http://www.rizon.be (flash site) works well , seems that FB doesn't like the new site :s